# How do I prove the following statement regarding partitions of a set?

Tags: proof-writing, set-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, set-partition

$\exists! x:Px\implies (\forall x(Px \implies Qx) \iff \exists x(Px \land Qx))$

Essentially, the values of x for which P is true form partitions of the universe. This question came to mind when considering the definition of the absolute value of real numbers:

$abs=\{ (x,y)|(x>0 \implies y=x) \land (x\le 0 \implies y=-x)\}$

Which is actually equivalent to:

$abs=\{ (x,y)|x>0 \land y=x \lor x\le 0 \land y=-x\}$

In this case we have only 2 partitions, $\{ x|x>0\}$ and $\{x|x\le 0\}$. I am able to prove the equivalency of the two definitions of the absolute value function using rules from propositional logic, but I have difficulty when facing 3, 4 or more partitions, hence why I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $\exists!x\colon Px$.

So let $x_0$ with $Px_0$ and $\forall x\colon Px\to x=x_0$.

Assume $\forall x(Px\to Qx)$.
By specialization, $Px_0\to Qx_0$. By modus ponens, $Qx_0$. As also $Px_0$, we have $Px_0\land Qx_0$, hence $\exists x(Px\land Qx)$. This proves
$$ \forall x(Px\to Qx)\to\exists x(Px\land Qx) .$$

Next, assume $\exists x(Px\land Qx)$ and let $x_1$ with $Px_1\land Qx_1$. In particular, $Px_1$. Specialize $\forall x\colon Px\to x=x_0$ to $Px_1\to x_1=x_0$, and so by modus ponens $x_1=x_0$. Also $Qx_1$, hence from $x_1=x_0$ also $Qx_0$. In order to show $\forall x(Px\to Qx)$, let $x$ be arbitrary and assume $Px$. Then again $x=x_0$, and so from $Qx_0$ also $Qx$. This shows $Px\to Qx$, and as $x$ was arbitrary, $\forall x(Px\to Qx)$. In summary, this proves
$$ \exists x(Px\land Qx)\to \forall x(Px\to Qx).$$

Combined, we have proved
$$ \forall x(Px\to Qx)\leftrightarrow\exists x(Px\land Qx) $$
under the assumption $\exists!x\colon Px$, so we can discharge one last time to

$$\exists!x\colon Px \to (\forall x(Px\to Qx)\leftrightarrow\exists x(Px\land Qx)). $$